# Почему обучение модели застревает на валидационных потерях в 0.02?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, tensorflow, keras, компьютерное-зрение

для обучения используется keras в составе tensorflow, задача-регрессия ограничивающего прямоугольника, вот модель:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(300, 300, 1))
x = DepthwiseConv2D((3, 3), padding="same")(inputs)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (1, 1), strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = DepthwiseConv2D((3, 3), padding="same")(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (1, 1), strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = DepthwiseConv2D((3, 3), padding="same")(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (1, 1), strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = DepthwiseConv2D((3, 3), padding="same")(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (1, 1), strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(512)(x)
out = Dense(4, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = Model(inputs, out)
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001), loss="mse", metrics=[iou], run_eagerly=True)
```

То есть архитектура довольно схожа с MobileNet, обучение происходит при batch_size=128 и количество тренировочных и валидационных данных 2000 и 750 соответственно
Результат модели-выдача x,y верхнего левого и правого нижнего углов, все метки нормализованы между 0 и 1 (сигмоида обоснована)
Тем не менее уже после первых нескольких эпох (от 1 до 3) валидационная функция потерь застревает на 0.02 (0.0199-0.0203) и никуда из этого диапазона не выходит
При этом другие модели работают хорошо
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем загвоздка?

Comment: Без данных это только гадать. Ну попробуйте `Dropout`-ов накидать, чтобы не застревал, фиг его знает. И почему `optimizer` не `Adam` традиционно, например? Я не силён в нейросетках, но попробовал бы этим тоже поиграться. А может `lr` маленькая слишком и опять же где-то застревает в локальном минимуме. Я идей то много могу накидать, но без данных какой смысл.

Comment: Заметил такую фишку, что если убрать первые 2 слоя точечной свертки, то сеть начинает обучаться нормально
Дать объяснение этому я не могу